# How to bind a Rust service running on Clever Cloud with a custom domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, clever-cloud

I have deployed my Rust service to the Clever Cloud platform. It works as expected on PROD and localhost.

How I can bind my custom domain with deployed Rust service?

For example, to make request to my service you can call: https://app-29b1f7f3-49c6-4695-8772-e0f34d438327.cleverapps.io/hey

I'd like to make requests to the service from my custom domain, so in my code I want to use just: `fetch('/hey')`.

I added CNAME to my domain provider, but still unable to get expected response.

Because I don't have any experience in backend/clever cloud, I don't know what else you need to be able to answer on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working at Clever Cloud.

You can found how to link your domain to your clever app [here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/administrate/domain-names/).

Feel free to contact us through our support chat.

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Gaël Reyrol
I have already did this. Btw, clever cloud support is excellent!